# Why does trim() NOT remove char 160?

Tags: apex, string

I have a scenario where the label of a `PicklistEntry` contains a char 160 (non breaking space) at the end of the value. So when I call `pe.label.getChars()` the array output is the following characters: `(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 160)`.

If I call `trim()` then `getChars()`, I'm expecting the trailing 160 character to be removed.  However, it's not.  When I use char 32, `trim()` will remove it correctly.

Additionally, using `normalizeSpace()` DOES remove the char 160.

So my main question is why doesn't `trim()` remove this character while `normalizeSpace()` does?

See code example below.

```
// get 'hello ' from character array using 160 for space
String hello = String.fromCharArray(new Integer[] { 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 160 });
System.debug('==>' + hello.trim()); //output ==> 'hello '

// get 'hello ' from character array using 32 for space
hello = String.fromCharArray(new Integer[] { 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32 });
System.debug('==>' + hello.trim()); //output ==> 'hello'

// get 'hello ' from character array using 160 for space and call normalizeSpace()
hello = String.fromCharArray(new Integer[] { 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 160 });
System.debug('==>' + hello.normalizeSpace()); //output ==> 'hello'
```

**EDIT**
Additionally, when calling `normalizeSpace()` the char 160 is actually converted to char 32.  So in order to completely trim the 160 and additional 32, I have to call `normalizeSpace().trim()`

```
String hello = String.fromCharArray(new Integer[] { 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 160 });
String normalized = hello.normalizeSpace();
System.debug('==>' + normalized); //output ==> 'hello'
System.debug('==>' + normalized.getChars()); //output ==> (104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) for trim says:

> Leading and trailing ASCII control characters such as tabs and newline characters are also removed. White space and control characters that aren’t at the beginning or end of the sentence aren’t removed.

Taking this literally, only space (ASCII 32), tab (ASCII 9), line feed (ASCII 10), and carriage return (ASCII 13) would be removed, leaving other whitespace, such as non-breaking space, zero-width space, and so on unaffected. This is probably because trim is a *very* old method, dating back to the beginning of Apex, while normalizeWhitespace is relatively new.

---

As a quick alternative that should do what you want:

```
// get ' hello ' from character array using 160 for space
String hello = String.fromCharArray(new Integer[] { 160, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 160 });
System.debug('==>"' + hello.replaceAll('^\\p{IsWhite_Space}+|\\p{IsWhite_Space}+$','')+'"'); //output ==>"hello"
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.  Is it worth opening a ticket with support to suggest they include these additional characters in trim?  I could see a scenario where you don't want to use normalizeSpace since it removes dupes throughout the entire string.

Comment: @fehays You could try, but my best educated guess is that they would not log a bug, or if they did, it would become Closed/NoFix. If you need a more robust solution, consider String.replaceAll, which accepts a regular expression to replace. For example: `^\\p{IsWhite_Space}+|\\p{IsWhite_Space}+$`. I'll include an example for you in the answer.